# ArrayOutOfBoundsException when using projection in HQL for a java.util.Map in a component

Tags: hibernate

I want to persist the following Event class:

```java
public class Event {
  private Long id;
  private LocalizableString name = new LocalizableString();
  /* setters and getters */
}
```

Into a database with hibernate. Here is the class "LocalizableString":

```java
public class LocalizableString {
  private Map<Locale, String> values = new HashMap<Locale, String>();
  /* setters and getters */
}
```

So here is the mapping that I created:

```xml
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="path.to.my.Event" table="MyEventTable">
      <id name="id" column="Un_ID" type="java.lang.Long">
        <generator class="path.to.my.IDGenerator" />
      </id>
      <component name="name">
        <map name="values" table="NamesOfMyEvents">
          <key column="event_id"/>
          <map-key column="locale" type="java.util.Locale"/>
          <element column="value" type="string"/>
        </map>
      </component>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

At first everything looks fine. I can fill the map of my name attribute with plenty of translations of names, I can persist those names and I can retrieve the Event back from DB. Looking at my DB directly using SQL everything looks fine as well.

But then came the day when I wanted to use projection and execute the following HQL-Query:

```sql
select e.name from Event e where id = :id
```

Now I get the following Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.util.ColumnHelper.generateScalarColumns(ColumnHelper.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.setScalarColumnText(DotNode.java:667)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.renderScalarSelects(SelectClause.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:619)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:672)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:288)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1651)
```

Well, that sucks. Is there anything I can do about it? I am using Hibernate 3.3.2. I am aware that the version is quite old, but it is not that easy for me to upgrade. So in case this is a bug, a workaround is much appreciated. Knowing which version fixes the problem would also be useful information.